# how to change label on jqplot stacked horizontal bar chart

Tags: jquery, jqplot, bar-chart

I'm using jqplot to create a stacked horizontal bar chart using the code shown here:

```
perc_data = [[[6, "1"]], [[92, "1"]], [[1, "1"]], [[1, "1"]]];
series_array = [ { label: "Mud", color: "#ccaa00"}, { label: "Sand", color: "#ffeecc"}, 
                 { label: "Gravel", color: "#dddddd"}, { label: "Rock", color: "#664400"} ];
var perc_chart = $.jqplot('perc_div', perc_data, {
    stackSeries: true,
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        shadowAngle: 135,
        rendererOptions: {  barWidth: 25,
                            barDirection: 'horizontal',
        }
    },
    series: series_array,
    axes: {
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {  tickRenderer: $.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer, 
                                tickOptions: {  mark: null,
                                                fontSize: 12
                                             }
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            numberTicks: 6
        }
    },
    grid: {
        drawGridlines: false,
        drawBorder: false,
        shadow: false
    }
});
```

The resulting bar chart looks like this:

[image]

What I'd like to do next is change the label of the bar from '1' to 'My Label'.
I would have thought I could simply change `perc_data` from its original value to the following:

```
perc_data = [[[6, "My Label"]], [[92, "My Label"]], [[1, "My Label"]], [[1, "My Label"]]];
```

But that results in an empty bar chart:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I might tweak this label.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [ticks option (2nd example on this page)](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html):

```
perc_data = [[[6, "1"]], [[92, "1"]], [[1, "1"]], [[1, "1"]]];
ticks = ["My Label"];

series_array = [ { label:'Mud', color:"#ccaa00"}, { label:"Sand", color:"#ffeecc"}, { label:"Gravel", color:"#dddddd"}, { label:"Rock", color:"#664400"} ];

var perc_chart = $.jqplot('chart1', perc_data, {
    stackSeries: true,
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        shadowAngle: 135,
        rendererOptions: {  barWidth: 25,
                            barDirection: 'horizontal',
        }
    },
    series: series_array,
    axes: {
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {  tickRenderer: $.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer, 
                                tickOptions: {  mark: null,
                                                fontSize: 12
                                             }
            },
            ticks: ticks
        },
        xaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            numberTicks: 6
        }
    },
    grid: {
        drawGridlines: false,
        drawBorder: false,
        shadow: false
    }
});
```

[image]

BTW, `{ label="Mud", color="#ccaa00"}` is not valid javascript should be `{ label:"Mud", color:"#ccaa00"}`

Comment: Thanks Mark!  (And thanks for catching the js typo -- that was part of an attempt to simplify the code for this example -- I've updated my example with your fix.)

Comment: +1 @mark This helped me figure out how to limit to 100 ( i've been trying to use forceTickAt100: true but it don't work.)
Thanks